# find the length of a string in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a script for google sheet, who can count a letter in a text. But it seems that .length doesn't work. Anyone who can give directions on where to find the the solution.

```
    function Tjekkode(tekst , bogstav){
    var test = "";
    // find the length of laengdeTekst
    var laengdeTekst = tekst.length;
    var t = 0;
    // through the text character by character
    for ( var i = 1; i<laengdeTekst ; i++) {

     var test = tekst.substr(i,1);
     if (test == bogstav) {
      // if the letter is found, it is counted up
      // REMEMBER == means compare
      var t = t + 1;
     }
    }
    // returns percent appearance of the letter
    Return = t / længdeTekst * 100
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

length is ok in your code. To test it, run this script:

```
function test( ) {

   var test = "123456";
   // finder længden på teksten
   var laengdeTekst = test.length;
   Logger.log(laengdeTekst);
}
```

After you run it, check Log, press [Ctrl + Enter]

---

The correct code in your case:

```
function Tjekkode(tekst, bogstav) {
  var test = "";

  var laengdeTekst = tekst.length;
  var t = 0;
  
  // start looping from zero!
  for ( var i = 0; i<laengdeTekst; i++) {

    var test = tekst.substr(i,1);
    if (test == bogstav) {
      var t = t + 1;
    }
  }

  // JavaScript is case sensitive: 'return != Return'
  return t / laengdeTekst * 100;  
}
```

Please, look at [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp) for more info

Comment: Nice answer, Max. You've been pretty active on the GAS-related tags, that's nice to see! One request: as well as answering, take a moment to edit questions to improve them, especially the tags which are often wrong. For instance, this question should be tagged with google-apps-script. It should also be in English - while it's usually best for the OP to fix that, you can do it yourself if they won't; it improves the searchability and usefulness of questions & answers to do it. Bonus: you can work towards the rare [illuminator badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator)!

Answer (score 0):

thanks
I'll guess that I might get the one with the R instead of r at the end, but the script didn't run that line, because it kinda stopped at the .length line :/

the comments in danish is for my pupils (I'm a teacher in elementary school)

I'll see if google wants to cooperate today :|

Answer (score 0):

This is the google script that worked for me. Note the 24 - that's the length of an empty message that has markup like `<div>...</div>`

```
function TrashEmptyDrafts() {
  var thread = GmailApp.getDraftMessages();
  for (var i = 0; i < thread.length; i++) {
    b=thread[i].getBody();

    if (b.length <= 24.0){
      thread[i].moveToTrash();
    }  
  }}
```